# How do I transfer iTunes on a PC to my new iPhone 6?

Tags: itunes, data-transfer, iphone, windows

When I connect my iPhone 6 to my PC in order to transfer my music, I am told that the I need the newest edition of iTunes. When I try to download the newest edition of iTunes, I am told that the update is for Windows7 or higher. (I have Windows XP.) Microsoft no longer offers support for Windows XP. How else can I get my music from my PC to my iPhone 6?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't upgrade from Windows XP you could use [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/), however I'd strongly recommend upgrading to a newer OS and using iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're stuck.
The latest iTunes will not run on anything lower than Windows 7.

For many reasons, not least your own security, your solution is to be on Windows 7 at least.